Minio and a NodeJS API in a docker-compose project: how to handle presigned URLs?
I am working on a Webapp, that contains a Backend and a Frontend (both in NodeJS, the first using Express and the second using Next.JS), in addition to a MariaDB and a Minio services.
I want to be able to deploy them first locally for a local demo on my PC. Therefore, I tried first to deploy them one by one, which works. Now, I want a docker-compose.yaml file that will handle everything for me in one command (for a latter transformation into a Kubernetes project, for an easy cloud deployment).
The problem I have now is that when I ask Minio for a pre-signed URL using my Backend, it gives me a URL with as domain name the name of the service of Minio (here, minio). I would like to have a URL with as domain name "localhost" for instance so that my local demo works fine.
Here is the docker-compose.yaml file:
version: '3'

services:
    mariadb:
        # content of the service

    minio:
        image: 'minio/minio:latest'
        container_name: minio
        ports:
            - '${BUCKET_S3_PORT_PUBLIC}:${BUCKET_S3_PORT_PRIVATE}'
            - '${BUCKET_S3_CONSOLE_PORT_PUBLIC}:${BUCKET_S3_CONSOLE_PORT_PRIVATE}'
        networks:
            - network
        environment:
            MINIO_ROOT_USER: ${BUCKET_S3_ROOT_USERNAME}
            MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${BUCKET_S3_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MINIO_BROWSER: on
            MINIO_ADDRESS: ':${BUCKET_S3_PORT_PRIVATE}'
            MINIO_CONSOLE_ADDRESS: ':${BUCKET_S3_CONSOLE_PORT_PRIVATE}'
            MINIO_SERVER_URL: 'http://localhost:${BUCKET_S3_PORT_PUBLIC}'
        volumes:
            - 'minio:/data/minio'
        command: 'minio server /data/minio'
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - curl
                - '-f'
                - 'http://${BUCKET_S3_URL}:${BUCKET_S3_PORT_PUBLIC}/minio/health/live'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s

    backend:
        container_name: backend
        build:
            context: ./path-to-api/
        ports:
            - "${API_PORT_PRIVATE}:${API_PORT_PRIVATE}"
        networks:
            - network
        environment:
            BUCKET_S3_ROOT_USERNAME: "${BUCKET_S3_ROOT_USERNAME}"
            BUCKET_S3_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${BUCKET_S3_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
            BUCKET_S3_NAME_PUBLIC: "${BUCKET_S3_NAME_PUBLIC}"
            BUCKET_S3_NAME_PRIVATE: "${BUCKET_S3_NAME_PRIVATE}"
            BUCKET_S3_URL: "${BUCKET_S3_URL}"
            BUCKET_S3_PORT: ${BUCKET_S3_PORT_PUBLIC}
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
            - minio
        restart: always

    frontend:
        # content of the service, depends on backend

networks:
    network:

volumes:
    minio:
        driver: local

Here is my NodeJS method to get URLs:
const minioClient = new Minio.Client({
    endPoint: BUCKET_URL,
    port: BUCKET_PORT,
    useSSL: false,
    accessKey: BUCKET_USERNAME,
    secretKey: BUCKET_PASSWORD
})

function getFileURL(bucketName, fileName, callback) {
    minioClient.presignedGetObject(bucketName, fileName, function(err, url) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }
        callback(null, url);
    });
}

Here are the environment variables I use:
BUCKET_S3_URL="minio"
BUCKET_S3_PORT_PRIVATE=9000
BUCKET_S3_PORT_PUBLIC=9000
BUCKET_S3_CONSOLE_PORT_PRIVATE=8900
BUCKET_S3_CONSOLE_PORT_PUBLIC=8900
BUCKET_S3_ROOT_USERNAME="minio"
BUCKET_S3_ROOT_PASSWORD="password"

The MINIO_SERVER_URL environment variable is ignored, and still returns URLs like http://minio:9000/path/to/data.ext.
Also, I cannot use "localhost" as the BUCKET_S3_URL environment variable, since they are in two containers. I use "minio" because they are on the same network.
If I forgot anything, please feel free to ask me about more information. Thanks!
